# When is shopify shop/update webhook called?

Tags: php, events, shopify, webhooks

I set up a shop/update webhook in my shopify app but I'm not able to make it work. If I add the same url via shopify notifications my url is called just fine.
But if I change my shop name, emails, currency etc I don't get any call.

What does "shop/update" actually stand for? What should be updated so that I get notified?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

There's some strange issue related to my working environment I guess. I have a local php script "waiting" for webhooks from shopify. Then there's a ultrahook thing set up which basically listens to webhooks on public hostname and forwards them to my local project.

The strange thing is that I:
- DO NOT get actual shop/update topic webhook calls to my local project via ultrahook (ultrahook seems not to get them, not an issue with my project)
- DO get shop/update webhook calls to other servers
- DO get other topic webhook calls to my local project via ultrahook
- DO get shop/update webhook calls to my local project via utrahook IF I initiate them by clicking "Test webhook" in shopify

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the webhook was correctly set up when you installed the app? You can check it through the API

Comment: Yes, I did that. It's there. It's stranger than I thought. Seems to be working if I change the url to another server, if I click "Test" in manually added notification or if I use another topic (like product updated). Very odd. Wrote in the shopify forum and emailed the admins.

Comment: Sounds weird! What URL endpoint are you using?

Comment: I use ultrahook.com to forward the webhook calls to my local environment. I though that's where the problem is. But this doesn't explain why "test clicking" or other webhook topics work fine with the same url

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty illogical. I normally use localtunnel.me and it works fine. Have you checked the protocol? It seems that ultrahook works on HTTP, could you webhook url be set up as HTTPS?

Comment: The url is http and gets forwarded to https. As i mentioned other topics work fine with the same setup and url. I'll check localtunnel.me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

shop/update webhook fire when you change data like product, collection, pages etc only. This could be the reason you are not notifying when updating shop email.

Comment: Not true. Product updates have separate webhook topics. Shop/update actually does fire. Apparently it's related to some very specific ultrahook/webhook topic situation. I'll update my question